# Rss to html causes whole page to redirect on Safari

Tags: jquery, redirect, safari, rss, feed

I have just embeded a javascript feed on this website it appears just fine on most browsers, although on Safari it seems to cause it to show just the feed itself. What seems to be happening? It doesn't do this on most other browsers. You can view it [here.](http://instantinteriors.com.au/blog.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks fine to me on Chrome (Windows) and also on Safari (Mac).

As an aside, the font renders badly for me on Chrome/Win

Comment: Thanks, fixed some code. Now just have to work out how to make different font appear for different res.